# How does one prove that the Klein bottle cannot be embedded in $R^3$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

How does one prove that the Klein bottle cannot be embedded in $R^3$?
I'm talking about smooth embeddings.

Comment: Have tried to build one?

Answer (score 5):

Any compact, smooth hypersurface in $\Bbb R^n$ is necessarily orientable. (Without fancy algebraic topology, this is a consequence of the Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem.) Indeed, more is true: A compact hypersurface in any simply connected manifold is orientable.

Comment: Isn't the mobius strip a compact smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb R^3$ which is not orientable? Or does the hypersurface need to be closed?

Comment: @Cubi73: Yes, I of course mean a manifold with no boundary, but of course I should have been explicit.  (I'm in the collection of geometers who insist on saying "with boundary" if boundary is allowed. Of course, saying "closed" as you did is just as ambiguous, except — again — for custom.

Answer (score 1):

[MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18987/why-cant-the-klein-bottle-embed-in-mathbbr3). In the link, there is a reference to a proof in Hatcher using Alexander duality as well as a more elementary proof.

Comment: For a homological proof for all dimensions see my answer in                                                            http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553939/are-closed-properly-embedded-manifolds-of-co-dimension-1-in-mathbbrn-orie/605060#605060                                          The method works for the general case of orientable simply connected manifolds.