# Why is the Klein bottle not homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

It is stated in may books and also in the wikipedia or WolframMathWorld that the Klein bottle is not homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. Why is it so?

Comment: Related: [How does one prove that the Klein bottle cannot be embedded in $R^{3}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611834)

Comment: Also this one on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18987/why-cant-the-klein-bottle-embed-in-mathbbr3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If so, one could apply [Alexander Duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality) to conclude that $$H_2(\text{Klein bottle},\mathbb{Z}) \approx \widetilde H_0(\mathbb{R}^3 - (\text{Klein bottle})) \approx \mathbb{Z}
$$
contradicting that $H_2(\text{Klein bottle},\mathbb{Z})$ is trivial.