# Smooth surfaces that isn't the zero-set of $f(x,y,z)$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

The zero-set of any smooth function $f(x,y,z)$ with a non-vanishing gradient is a smooth surface. I was wondering if the reverse is true: is every smooth surface in $E^3$ the zero-set of some smooth function? If not, what do the counterexamples look like?

I was thinking that a plane with a hole may qualify as a counterexample, but I have yet to prove it.

Comment: At the very least, you need the surface $S$ to be closed in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: It's also worth knowing that any surface is at least *locally* the zero-set of a smooth function.

Answer (score 38):

More generally, a smooth embedded   closed hypersurface  $S\subset \mathbb R^n$, compact or not, is indeed the zero locus of a smooth function $F:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ satisfying $dF(s)\neq 0$ for all $s\in S$ .
**Proof:**
There exists an open covering $\mathscr U=(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of $\mathbb R^n$, smooth functions $f_i$ on $U_i$ and smooth nowhere zero functions $g_{ij}$ on $U_i\cap U_j$ satisfying $S\cap U_i=f_i^{-1}(0)$, $df_i(s)\neq 0$ for $s\in S\cap U_i$ and $f_i=g_{ij}f_j$ on $U_i\cap U_j$.
[This is easily seen to be equivalent to the more orthodox  definition of closed submanifold]
The $g_{ij}$'s form a cocycle and thus  define a smooth line bundle $L$ on $\mathbb R^n$ which, like all line bundles on the contractible manifold $\mathbb R^n$, is trivial.
So our cocycle is a coboundary, which means that we can  find non vanishing smooth functions $g_i$ on $U_i$ such that $g_{ij}=g_j. g_i  
^{-1}$ on $U_i\cap U_j$.
We then have $f_ig_i=f_jg_j$ on $U_i\cap U_j$ so that these funtions $f_ig_i$ on $U_i$ glue to a global smooth function $F:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ satisfying $F\vert U_i=f_ig_i$, and $F:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$  is the required equation for $S$: $$S=F^{-1}(0) \;\text{and}\; dF(s)\neq 0 \; \text {for every } \;s\in S$$
**Remarks**
1) **Every** closed subset of $\mathbb R^n$, smooth or not,  is the zero set of a global smooth function (Whitney) but of course one can say nothing *a priori* on the gradient of that function on the subset if it is not smooth.

2) This proof uses tools introduced more than 60 years ago in complex analysis ("solution of Cousin II problem").
It is a bit depressing that less than  1% of graduate students (my guess) could come up with such an easy proof and that (to my knowledge) zero textbook on differential geometry/topology (excluding those devoted to complex analysis specifically)  contain the relevant material for such a proof.

3) Notice carefully that the covering $\mathscr U=(U_i)_{i\in I}$ must cover all of $\mathbb R^n$, not just $S$ !
The best way to ensure this is to add to the covering the open set $U_0=\mathbb R^n\setminus S$ and to use the smooth function $f_0=1$ to describe  the intersection $S\cap U_0=\emptyset=f_0^{-1}(0)$.

**Edit**
The line bundle $L$ defined by the $g_{ij}$'s restricts to the normal bundle of $S$ in $\mathbb R^n$: $L|S=N_{S/\mathbb R^n}$ (cf. "First adjunction formula", [Grauert-Fritzsche](http://books.google.fr/books/about/From_Holomorphic_Functions_to_Complex_Ma.html?id=jSeRz36zXIMC&redir_esc=y), page 215).
Since $L$ is trivial, so is its restriction to $S$ and thus $S$ has a trivial normal bundle which proves that $S$ is orientable.
Thus the above answer also contains  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/864058/3217), whose technique I have shamefully plagiarized here.

Comment: Shouldn't $S$ be involved in the definition somewhere?

Comment: Dear @zibadawa: of course! I forgot to write  that on $U_i$ the surface  $S$ is the zero locus of $f_i$: I have added it in my answer now. Thanks a lot for your attentive reading.

Comment: Dear Georges, which part of your proof uses closedness of $S$? Unfortunately, I cannot see this on my own.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval The existence of open covering of $\mathbb R^n$, but not $S$.

Comment: Frank is right: if $S$ were not closed it would have a boundary point $p \notin S$ and at that boundary point one could not find a pair $U_i,f_i$ defining $S\cap U_i$ in the manner described in the answer.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I want to upvote this a million times if I could, just for the line "less than 1% of the graduate students..". (I'm a grad student myself, in the other 99%, I will admit.) Thank you for opening my eyes.

Answer (score 4):

Georges Elencwajg's "easy proof" is providing a "global solution" to your problem. Locally one can argue as follows: A smooth surface $S\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ is produced by a $C^1$-map
$${\bf g}:\quad(u,v)\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{x&=g_1(u,v)\cr y&=g_2(u,v)\cr z&=g_3(u,v)\cr}\right.$$ with $d{\bf g}(u,v)$ having rank $2$ at all points $(u,v)$ in sufficiently small neighborhoods $U$ of ${\bf p}$. We may assume that
$$\det\left[\matrix{g_{1.u}&g_{1.v}\cr g_{2.u}& g_{2.v}\cr}\right]\ne0\qquad\bigl((u,v)\in U\bigr)\ .$$
By the inverse function theorem it follows that there is a neighborhood $V$ of ${\bf q}=\bigl(g_1({\bf p}), g_2({\bf p})\bigr)$ and a $C^1$-inverse ${\bf h}'=(h_1,h_2)$ of ${\bf g}'=(g_1,g_2)$ mapping $V$ onto $U$. This mapping ${\bf h}'$ computes $(u,v)\in U$ for given $(x,y)$ in $V$. From this we can conclude that $S$ can be as well be presented by the map
$${\bf f}:\quad(x,y)\mapsto\bigl(x,y,\>g_3\bigl(h_1(x,y),h_2(x,y)\bigr)\bigr)\ .$$
Letting
$$g_3\bigl(h_1(x,y),h_2(x,y)\bigr)=:f(x,y)$$
the surface $S$ appears as solution set of the equation
$$z-f(x,y)=0\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

I find Georges Elencwajg's answer very interesting. We could state it in the following way:

the condition on the $f_i$’s is equivalent to say that they define a line bundle on $R^n$ together with a section $\sigma$ (in algebraic geometry they would define a Cartier divisor). The differential of the $f_i$’s non vanishing on $S$ means that this section is transverse to the zero-section. The line bundle being trivial means that we have a section of the trivial bundle, transverse to the zero section, hence a function on $R^n$ whose gradient is non vanishing on its zero-locus.

I am writing here as I wonder whether there is a more elementary way to prove this, without using line bundle techniques. A partition of the unity would’t work I think.