# Why does $\mathbb{RP}^2$ not continuously embed in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Ok, I know the answer: any closed hypersurface of $\mathbb R^3$ is orientable while $\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$ is not.

But I know how to prove that only for smooth embeddings. Is there a *simple* way to prove that there is no continuous embedding of the projective plane in Euclidean tridimensional space?

Comment: Do you know Alexander duality ?

Comment: Any compact topological submanifold $X^n\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ must have $H_{n-1}(X)$ torsion-free, which fails for $X = \mathbb{RP}^2$. This result is proved in, for example, Hatcher, via Alexander duality.

Comment: @Max By Alexander duality one gets that $H_1(\mathbb R^3\setminus\mathbb R\mathbb P^2)$ should be $\mathbb Z/2/\mathbb Z$, right? Then you have to show that no open subset of $\mathbb R^3$ has such property.

Comment: @anomaly ok, I'll check Hatcher book.

Comment: For Alexander duality, we may embed $\mathbb R^3\to S^3$ and we get an embedding $\mathbb RP^2\to S^3$. Now look at $H^3(S^3\setminus \mathbb RP^2)$, which should be $\mathbb Z$ : an open subset (hence open submanifold) of an orientable manifold is orientable as well

Answer (score 11):

The answers I've found in MathSE ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863960/orientation-of-hypersurface/864058#864058), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1031246/59234)) indeed appear to assume smoothness.

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the embedding of a compact hypersurface on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since it is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can also embed it in $S^3$. By Alexander-Poincaré duality, $\check{H}^{2}(A;\mathbb{Z}) \simeq H_1(S^3,S^3-A;\mathbb{Z})$, and this latter one is isomorphic to $\widetilde{H}_0(S^3-A;\mathbb{Z})$. (This can be seen by looking at the reduced exact sequence of the pair $(S^3,S^3-A)$.) Therefore, $\check{H}^{2}(A;\mathbb{Z})$ must be a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Once we know that $\check{H}^{2}(A;\mathbb{Z}) \simeq H^{2}(A;\mathbb{Z})$, the result then follows from the fact that $H^{2}(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$. Here's where smoothness simplifies things: it is relatively easy to see the isomorphism between Čech cohomology and singular cohomology in the case of a smooth embedding, due to the tubular neighbourhood theorem. However, it requires some work to see that this is true also when $A$ is an embedded topological manifold. For details, see Bredon's [*Geometry and Topology*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387979263)'s appendix "Euclidean Neighborhood Retracts". (Note that the isomorphism is not true in general, but it is true for reasonable spaces such as CW-complexes.)