# Can you distinguish topological properties of (sub)spaces by embedding them in an ambient space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm curious, but I can't seem to reason through it myself.

For instance, is it logical to deduce things like "[0,1] is not homeomorphic to (0,1)" by considering both as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, where we have tools like the Heine-Borel theorem?  Can this be done in general with other spaces and topological invariants?

Thanks,

Edit: For what it's worth, I'm not concerned about the particular example (but thank you for your answers anyway). I just chose something familiar and simple to illustrate the point.  I just wanted to know if it's possible (or useful) to determine topological properties this way.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do with them. In this particular case, the Heine-Borel theorem would tell you that $[0, 1]$ and $(0, 1)$ are and are not compact, respectively, but that's nothing new; the proof of the theorem boils down to showing that $[0, 1]$ is compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly use the Heine-Borel theorem to show that $[0,1]$ is compact, which distinguishes it topologically from $(0,1)$.

You can use embeddings to compute various invariants. For example, let $i : S^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be the usual embedding of the unit $n$ sphere. Then we get a decomposition of vector bundles $i^*(T(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}) = T(S^n) \oplus N$, where $N$ is the normal bundle.

There is a map $w : Vect(X) \to H^*(X ; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ that sends an isomoprhism class of real vector bundle to a certain cohomology class called the Steifel Whitney class. Among other properties, it satisfies $w(E \oplus E') = w(E) \cup w(E')$ an for $F$ a trivial bundle, $w(F) = 1$.

Thus, from the above formula $i^*(T(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}) = T(S^n) \oplus N$, where we note that $i^*(T(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$ an $N$ are trivial bundles, we get that $w(T(S^n)) = 1$.

(Note: This does *not* imply that $T(S^n)$ is trivial. Indeed, it generally is not, see the examples here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold )

This presumably lets you distinguish the sphere from something. I'm not sure what though.

---

Using the same argument, we can show that we *cannot* embed $\mathbb{RP}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$, for certain $n$. Let take $n = 2$ for simplicity, to try to get the result that we cannot embed the real projective plane into 3-space.

If we could, then we would get that $w(T(\mathbb{RP}^2)) = 1$, by the same argument as for the sphere.

Major Edit: We need a lemma to ensure that the normal bundle to a closed codimension one manifold $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is trivial. If $M$ is the zero set of a smooth function $f$, which has non-vanishing gradient along $M$, the normla bundle is trivial, for then the gradient of $f$ provides a nowhere vanishing normal vector field. This is how we know that the sphere's normal bundle is trivial, for instance.

Now, it is proven here: [Smooth surfaces that isn't the zero-set of $f(x,y,z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879334/smooth-surfaces-that-isnt-the-zero-set-of-fx-y-z/879449#879449) that every smooth codimension 1 submanifold $S$ of Euclidean space is cut out by an equation whose gradient is nonzero along that submanifold.

End Major Edit.

However, we can compute $w(T(\mathbb{RP}^2))$ by separate means, and see that it is not $1$. In fact, it suffices to know that for any bundle $E$, the first Steifel Whitney class of $E$ (which is the degree 1 component of $w(E)$) is zero iff $E$ is orientable. Since $T(\mathbb{RP}^2)$ is non-orientable, $w(T(\mathbb{RP}^2) \not = 1$.

The same style of argument would presumably show that any non-orientable closed $n$ manifold cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$, modulo that lemma.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class#Axiomatic_definition

---

You can presumably run the above proof without mentioning Stiefel-Whitney classes once; you can find direct proofs on this webpage that closed hypersurfaces of Eucliean space are orientable, so this gives an application of an embedding to proving an intrinsic statement.

---

A bit of philosophy: Embeddings of a compact manifold $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$ have tubular neighborhoods, and these tubular neighborhoods are like vector bundles on $M$. So, in some sense which I do not know enough about to make precise, studying embeddings of $M$ and vector bundles on $M$ are closely related. The study of vector bundles on $M$ contains a lot of information about $M$. Maybe someone more knowlegable can say something about this?

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @MathIsArt I think there is an error or gap in my answer, because I don't see why the normal bundle to the hypothesized embedding would be to trivial. Will update later.

Comment: @MathIsArt Okay, updated. I think it's correct now, but I also realized the whole thing about Steifel-Whitney classes is probably overkill just for questions of orientability. Maybe a more succinct answer would be to point out that if you can embed your closed manifold as a hypersurface, then it is necessarily orientable. This might be easy to see from an embedding, but hard to see from an abstract definition of the manifold.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need Heine-Borel to see that $[0,1]$ is compact (it's an ordered space that is complete and has a minimum and a maximum), and $(0,1)$ is not compact (it's ordered and has no maximum). So it pays more to look at the internal structure, instead of how they are embedded into a larger space.

It's hard to deduce non-homeomorphism from embeddings in general. My hypothesis is that if we could prove it with an embedding argument, then there also is a good internal reason for it.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the topology of the original spaces. If the intervals $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ are equipped with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}$, then embedding them in $\mathbb{R}$ seems perfectly natural and right. If they have some other topology, then not so much. For example, if both spaces are equipped with the discrete topology, then they *are* homeomorphic.

Assuming they have the subspace topology from $R$, I would just point out that you can remove a point from $[0,1]$ without disconnecting it, which is not true for $(0,1)$. That seems easier than using some big theorem.